# Alternative to float CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a new app that serializes the topbar and sidebar and wraps them in a form tag, but prints the sidebar and results side by side.

So far I've tried to replicate it with flex, but unfortunately I haven't found a way. I only succeeded with float.
However, I would like to use flex, if it is possible.

In addition, the results may not be included in the form tag, since this form contains its own tags and would therefore cause errors.

```css
.app {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
    padding: 40px;
}

.form {
    display: unset;
}

.topbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0);
}

.sidebar {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.3);
}

.results {
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,255,0.3);
}

.app:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
    <form class="form">
        <div class="topbar">Topbar</div>
        <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    </form>
    <div class="results">results</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternatives to float css are [grids](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: With the current structure, neither flex or grid can do this by default.

Comment: You *could* use either by using `display:contents` on the form though...but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Like @Paulie_D said, the markup structure doesn't lend itself nicely to intended layout. I wonder if the HTML structure can be rethought. Could you provide a fuller code context? I guess the `form` contains actual form fields?

Comment: *that serializes the topbar and sidebar and wraps them in a form tag* <-- A `form` element will only capture the **values** of *form elements* (i.e. `input`, `select`). It won't capture elements themselves.

Comment: I am using jQuery to serialize the form like $('form.form').serialize();
I think the only way to achieve this is by splitting up topbar and sidebar in 2 separate forms and do the jQuery call for both of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can imitate `float` type of behavior with `margin-left/margin-right: auto` when using flexbox, but you have to adapt the markup a bit as there has to be a container (with `display: flex` set) containing the elements as direct children that you want to "float". Something like this:

```css
.app {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
    padding: 40px;
}
    .form__container {
        display: flex;
     }
        .form {
            width: 20%;
        }

.topbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0);
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.3);
}

.results {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto; /* this is the key to imitate float */
    background-color: rgba(0,255,255,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
    <div class="topbar">Topbar</div>
    <div class="form__container">
        <form class="form">
            <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
        </form>
        <div class="results">results</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but margin doesnt affect the flex elements at all in your example. Also topbar is not anymore in the form tag. Maybe in different browsers

Comment: Well, margin: auto does have an effect, but not visibly if the floated elements take up 100% of space, if you would make the `.results` div let's say 50%, it would behave like a right floated element, e.g. stick to the right side of the container.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, @Paulie_D answered my question. Thats exactly what I wanted! Thank you! :D

```css
.app {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
}

.form {
    display: contents;
}

.topbar {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0);
}

.sidebar {
    flex: 0 0 20%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.3);
}

.results {
    flex: 0 0 80%;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,255,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
    <form class="form">
        <div class="topbar">Topbar</div>
        <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    </form>
    <div class="results">results</div>
</div>
```